# How to find documentation for Map

Tags: scala

I'm trying to find documentation of the Map.toList method in Scala but looking at documentation this is a trait : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map . So how can I find the documentation for scala Map? WHen I instatiate a Map am I just instantiating the trait ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trait `scala.collection.immutable.Map` is a contract. It's valid for all implementations, so its documentation is a documentation for any immutable scala `Map`.

In current implementation method `Map.apply` (`Map(a -> b, c -> d, ...)`) creates [`HashMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap) for more than 4 elements.

There are also classes [`Map1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map%24%24Map1) - [`Map4`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map%24%24Map4) for 1-4 elements. Also there is a singleton `EmptyMap`.

But this behavior could be changed in next scala versions in case there will be better implementation for general purpose.

Comment: The question was "How to find documentation for Map?" …

Comment: @RandallSchulz: yes. And there is already a link to this documentation in the question. So I've tried to explain why OP should use this documentation. Also note that by default (with `import Predef._`) `collection.immutable.Map` is imported into the scope, not just `collection.Map`.

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24). Also [its source](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L1) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Traits cannot be instantiated. They are abstract by definition. If they're actually fully implemented, they can (appear to) be instantiated by creating an anonymous type at the point of instantiation:

```
val x = new FullyImplementedTraitName { }
```

As to your main question, the documentation for [scala.collection.Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html) should tell you everything you need to know. When you have the [full frameset](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html) for the ScalaDocs displayed the filter text field at the upper left allows you to narrow down the class and package list by entering a the name (or portion thereof) you're looking for.

Comment: Often it is also useful to look at the source code; unfortunately in this case the road to `Map` is long and torturous. That being said, the short explanation is that the construction of immutable `Map` instances is delegated to the `update` overrides of the `Map` implementations in https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala.

Comment: When you are instantiating Map, you are using the factory object at: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L72